# Python Image of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a folder with 230400 images, each representing one pixel in a 480 x 480 image.
How can I use Python to make a single image out of each image?

I tried to creat a npy-array but I believe it resulted in a 3d array instead of a 2d array:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

data = []
files = glob.glob("./data/*.PNG")
for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread(myFile)
    data.append(image)

print('shape:', np.array(data).shape)

np.save('data',data)
```

> Output: shape: (230400, 100, 100, 3)

How do I create a 2d array of images? And how do I convert it to an image?

Comment: Pre-allocate the numpy array in the desired shape and iterate over the pixels.

Comment: Are your *.PNG color images or grey values?

Comment: @Dschoni color images

Comment: How does an image represent 1 pixel?
'folder with 230400 images, each representing one pixel' ?

Comment: Could you please specify the shape of each "image" you have? is it (1,) or (3,)? Moreover could you specify type and range of pixel values? Are they uint8 (range from 0 to 255) or float (range from 0 to 1)?

Comment: @Alderven `480*480` is `230400`, not `160000`

Comment: Whilst not wishing to advocate violence... personally, I would bop anybody on the nose who gave me 230k single pixel images!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by creating an empty numpy image with the size of your output image. For each pixel load the image in.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

image_x = 480
image_y =480
files = glob.glob("./data/*.PNG")
output = np.zeros((image_x, image_y, 3))
for i in range(image_x):
  for j in range(image_y):
    pixel = cv2.imread(files[image_x*i+j])
    output[i,j] = pixel[0,0]
```

Note: This is neither fast nor nice, but explicit.

For saving, use `cv2.imwrite` on the resulting array as in:

```
cv2.imwrite('output.png', output)
```

Comment: I assumed, that the images you read in are in the shape of `[1,1,3]`.